# WSO2-IS - Service Providers Disappeared

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

WSO2-IS is not showing the Service Providers anymore that I've created on carbon application. If I go to the SP_APP table the Service Providers are there, as showing bellow:

[image: SP_APP table]

If I create a new one it shows on carbon application, but if I try to recreate one it shows a message saying that the Service Provider already exist.

What can I do to overcome?

WSO2-IS: 5.11.0 
MySql: 5.7.31 
Java:11.0.14

Comment: Did you come across this issue recently in the already functioning server? Did you enable any configs recently ?

Comment: The only thing I did was to clean up the tables from WSO2AM_DB, WSO2SHARED_DB and WSO2CARBON_DB, but it is all related to API Manager, no?

Comment: I've seen that WSO2SHARED_DB is shared between API manager and IS. Is there any way to recover what it was saved on database WSO2SHARED_DB? I don't have any backup :(.

Comment: Did you check the logs in the WSO2-IS console or the logs folder to see if there are any errors related to the Service Providers? This may help you identify the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @AldoInáciodaSilva Please check whether you can retrieve the applications via application GET rest API https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/develop/application-rest-api/#/Applications/getAllApplications or applications are can listed in the console application (https://<host>:<port>/console)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to recreate the WSO2SHARED_DB and WSO2_IDENTITY_DB databases since they work sincronized. And then reinstalled WSO2 Identity Server.